# Visual Studio Preview 17.7 on mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-mac

I am currently trying to set up a new environment on my mac, have Visual Studio for Mac installed but need to get the latest preview version of Visual Studio (17.7) running. Is there any way to do this without running a VM or getting a new machine entirely?

Have been searching for answers to this, but versioning of Visual Studio for Mac seems to be completely seperate from Visual Studio. Have downloaded the 17.7 installer but I can't run it on my mac.

Answer (score 0):

There are two installers for Visual Studio for Mac. To get the preview version of Visual Studio for Mac you should download the preview installer https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/preview/ which will install Visual Studio for Mac preview side by side with the current stable version, you already have installed.

Also note that Visual Studio for Mac 17.6 is currently in preview, not version 17.7.